# which is optimize way to store in arraylist absolute filepath or file object?

Tags: java, file, treemap

```
  TreeMap<String, ArrayList> deviceWiseFileMap=
              new TreeMap<String, ArrayList>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

In my project I have to create TreeMap object.In the treeMap object values will be stored in Arraylist object.Now I have two option to store data in arraylist first I directly store absolute filepath and second store file object.I want to know which is good way to store data in arraylist in terms of memory usage and faster retrieval from map.

Comment: You will have to update your question. I read it twice and do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Marcinek I have edit my question is it good for you to understand?

Answer (score 0):

If the file path is constant the use file paths else store the files as objects. Either way you will have to use collections. Retrieval of String items will be faster than actual file object.

Also if the files are large it might cause memory issues, so overall it is recommended to use string paths.

You can use a properties file to store the absolute path.

Comment: Is file size matter when we deal with file object?

Comment: Yes, the entire file will be stored in the memory.